# Test mocking return empty body

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to make testings for my user controller but when I run the test it fails because the response body is empty.

Note that the response code is 200 so i dont see where this problem comes from...

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {UserRestController.class})
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private UserService service;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private User user1;

    private User user2;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        this.user1 = User.builder()
                .email("doe.jean@mymel.com")
                .username("Djin")
                .build();
        this.user2 = User.builder()
                .email("doe.john@mymel.com")
                .username("Jodo")
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_shouldReturnAllUsers() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(service.getUsers(Pageable.unpaged())).thenReturn(new PageImpl<>(Arrays.asList(user1, user2)));
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(APIPaths.V1_USER_BASE + "/all")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                .andReturn();
        mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
                .andExpect(status().is(200))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.size()", Matchers.is(2)))
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your `Pageable.unpaged()` ?  Is  your `mvcResult` correct?

Comment: My mvcResult seems correct with a 200 response expected that there is no body nor headers... Whether pageable is null or unpaged, the result is the same.